# how can I change digits from latin to persian digits

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am using Drupal with localization module,
 in persian language,
I want in persian show persian digits instead latina digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `persiantools` module, it change digits from latina to persian and some another features.....

[persiantools](https://drupal.org/project/persiantools)